# 自作gemをpath指定でinstallしようとすると指定と異なるPathが参照される

Tags: ruby, rubygems

自作gemをGemfileで指定しinstallを試みた所、installを行うことが出来ず困っています。

GemFile

```
# Gemfile
gem 'gem-name', '0.0.1', :path => '/Users/foo/tmp/pkg/gem-name'
```

上記Gemfileでbundle installを行うと

```
Could not install to path '/Users/foo/tmp/pkg/gem-name/ruby/2.4.0' because a file already exists at that path. Either remove or rename the file so the directory can be created.
```

というエラーが返ってきます。
本来参照していないはずのPathを参照しているようなのですが呼び出し方、或いはrbenv等の設定に問題があるのでしょうか…？
解決策があればご教示いただきたいです。
もし質問させて頂くにあたって情報が不足していましたら大変お手数ですが、教えて頂けると助かります。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
#環境
rbenv 1.1.1
ruby 2.4.1
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path`で指定するのはgemファイルへのパスではなく、gem開発のルートディレクトリ（.gemspecがあるディレクトリ）です。

http://www.ohmyenter.com/how-to-make-a-gem-for-rails/

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。
> pathで指定するのはgemファイルへのパスではなく、gem開発のルートディレクトリ（.gemspecがあるディレクトリ）です。
指定するPathも間違えていたのですね…教えて頂きありがとうございます。

.gemspecがあるディレクトリを指定してみたのですが、質問させて頂いた際と同じエラー内容が返ってきてしまいました。
`/User/foo/gem開発のルートディレクトリ/ruby/2.4.0`
という形でPath末尾に指定していないPathが入ってしまうようです…

Comment: ひょっとしてgem開発プロジェクト内にGemfileを置いて、gemを使用しようとしていますか？

Comment: Gemfileを置いているのは別ディレクトリになります。
外部から開発プロジェクトを参照している様な形です。

Comment: なんとくなくですけど、bundlerのインストール先に問題があるように見受けられます。同Gemfileに書いてある他のgemのインストールは上手くいっているのでしょうか？ またそのインストール先にすでにpath指定したいgemが入ってたりしませんか？

Comment: 助言して頂いた情報を元にBundler周りについて調べてみた所、gemのインストール先をシステム環境でなくプロジェクトの任意ディレクトリ`vendor/bundle 等`を設定した場合`bundle exec ruby <実行対象となるrubyfile>`で指定しなければシステム環境を参照しに行ってしまうという記事をstackoverflowで見つけました。
これから詳細について学習しようと思っていますが、ruby実行時に,bundler/configから勝手に参照してくれるものだと思ってました。。。
itmammothさん、とても親切にコメントして頂きありがとうございました！

Comment: 上手くいって良かったです。rubyにしろrailsにしろ、それ自体の難しさだけでなく、それを取り巻く環境のことも勉強しなければいけなかったりして、初学者には大変だと思います。でも情報量は豊富だと思うので、めげずに地道に頑張ってください。